# Can assignment from a const_iterator dereference cause undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, undefined-behavior, const-iterator

This code is a simplified test for something I am trying to do for real elsewhere. I have a function which takes a "ref-to-ptr" argument and modifies it to return a pointer from a list of pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

typedef int* intp;
typedef std::list<intp> intplist;
intplist myList;

void func(intp &arg) // (1)
{
    intplist::const_iterator it = myList.begin();
    std::advance(it, 2);
    arg = *it;
}

int main()
{
    myList.push_back(new int(1));
    myList.push_back(new int(2));
    myList.push_back(new int(3));

    int* ip = NULL; // (2)
    func(ip);
    if (ip) cout << "ip = " << *ip << endl;
    else cout << "ip is null!" << endl;

    for (intplist::const_iterator it = myList.begin(); it != myList.end(); ++it) 
        delete *it;
    return 0;
}
```

It works and prints `ip = 3` as expected, only I am worried that it may be causing undefined behaviour or otherwise lead to trouble, because I am stripping away the constness of the iterator by assigning the result of it's dereferencing to the argument. I tried to add `const` at (1) and (2) but it didn't build.

Am I right to be worried? If so, why am I not getting a warning from g++ (4.9.2)?

Comment: "I tried to add const at (1) and (2) but it didn't build.": did you also add `const` to `intp` typedef?

Comment: No... I treated the typedef as a stupid string replacement macro and just placed the const in the `func` declaration: `void func(const intp &arg)`. Your way, it builds and works, but I don't understand what's the difference.

Comment: `intp` is a pointer. `const intp` is constant pointer, it says nothing about constness of the value it point to. When you say `typedef const int* intp`, you say that it will point to a const integer.

Comment: @neuviemeporte A typedef is not textual replacement, it's a semantic name for a type. `const intp &` is a reference to a constant `intp` - it's `int * const &`.

Comment: @Angew, any way to do it in case there is no typedef? My original example is a template function with a template-dependent type of the argument: `template <typename T> void GetItem( T list, const typename T::value_type &val )` - this will not build

Comment: @neuviemeporte To do what? "Inject" `const` into `value_type` if it's a pointer? For that, you could try [`std::add_pointer_t<std::add_const_t<std::remove_pointer_t<typename T::value_type>>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types)

Comment: @Angew: That was the idea, yes... looking at that, I wish I hadn't asked ;)

Comment: In any case, this was intented to be used with STL containers, so I can probably get away with `T::const_reference val`, but it's C++11 only. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is perfectly fine. You're not stripping away any constness (there's no way to do that implicitly in C++). `*it` gives you a `const intp &`. You're *copying* the pointer referred to by that reference into `arg`. Copying from something does not strip constness away. The assignment to `arg` assigns into `ip` in your case, it does not *bind* anything diretly to the `intp` object inside the container.

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, this means `*it` is "reference to a pointer to const int". How is it that I am able to assign that to `val`, which is "reference to pointer to int" (non-const)?

Comment: OK, I think I understand now - it is "const reference to pointer-to-int", right? The pointer was never const.

Comment: @neuviemeporte Yes, it'a "reference to a (constant (pointer to int))". Parentheses used in mathematical sense.

Answer (score 2):

const_iterator just means you can't assign to that iterator and/or can only call const functions on the object it points to. There is no problem with you copying the `value` - in this case a pointer. You are not storing const pointers, if you were, then you would have to assign to a const pointer